# HTML Email Styling/Formatting

Tags: html-email

I am trying to design an email template for a project. I have the CSS and HTML ready and working for the email template. My email template looks exactly the way I want when I view it in the browser however once the email is viewed in the email client(Gmail, Outlook). The styling, fonts, images are not getting applied.
My current email template structure :

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    /*Font import*/
    /*Class stylings*/
    /*Media query's*/
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- My email content -->
<div id="header">
      <div class="content-header-center">
        <div class="container">
          <a href="#" target="_blank"
            ><img
              alt="#"
              src="#"
            />
          </a>
          <div class="content-spot">
            <h1>
              <a href="#" target="_blank"
                >You are invited to the<br />
                presentation of the dawn</a
              >
            </h1>

            <p>&nbsp;</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
      <div class="container landing-page">
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using PHP to code the template and then mailing using mailgun(If relevant)
Can someone help me fix this

Comment: HTML email is severely restricted in what you can do. Lots of things won't work right; it's like coding in the 1990s. Webfonts, for example, only work in some clients: https://litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-web-fonts

Answer (score 1):

Email requires the CSS to be included at the beginning as the email would have no way to link to your CSS.  This is called inline CSS.

For more information you can check out:
https://css-tricks.com/using-css-in-html-emails-the-real-story/